# Riemann Integrable.

Tags: riemann-integration

We have some questions about Riemann integrable, so if $f,g$ are Riemann integrable
over $[a,b]$ denote by $f,g\in R[a,b]$, then $\max\{f,g\},\min\{f,g\}\in R[a,b]$.

So, it clearly ? , because in case $f<g$ then $\max\{f,g\}=g$

Since $g\in R[a,b]$ then $\max\{f,g\}\in R[a,b]$.

Similarly in case $g<f$.

Can some check that it true  ?

Comment: What if sometimes $f(x)>g(x)$ and then for another part of the interval we have $g(x)>f(x)$?

Comment: You can write $\max\{f,g\}$ ($\min$ too) as sum and product involving $f$ and $g$.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2054837/148510) is a Riemann sum approach or use the trick suggested by@LucasCorrêa.

Comment: Thanks, everyone.